# Weird error trying to chart data in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

very confused here and just not knowledgable enough to get to the bottom of the problem. I am charting data on the value of construction equipment in jupyter notebook, and everything is going great. Except, on one particular data set I keep getting an error. After googling and trying to find a solution myself I must come to stackoverflow. It's weird, because I am not doing anything different with this data set. I even tried recreating it. This is all I am doing:

```
dataretry.plot(kind="scatter", x="Price", y="Hours", alpha=0.3)
```

I expected a scatterplot to show. However, I get this massive error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3077             try:
-> 3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Price'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-81e70cca10a1> in <module>
----> 1 dataretry.plot(kind="scatter", x="Price", y="Hours", alpha=0.3)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __call__(self, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   2939                           fontsize=fontsize, colormap=colormap, table=table,
   2940                           yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 2941                           sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
   2942     __call__.__doc__ = plot_frame.__doc__
   2943 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in plot_frame(data, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   1975                  yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr,
   1976                  secondary_y=secondary_y, sort_columns=sort_columns,
-> 1977                  **kwds)
   1978 
   1979 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in _plot(data, x, y, subplots, ax, kind, **kwds)
   1741         if isinstance(data, ABCDataFrame):
   1742             plot_obj = klass(data, x=x, y=y, subplots=subplots, ax=ax,
-> 1743                              kind=kind, **kwds)
   1744         else:
   1745             raise ValueError("plot kind %r can only be used for data frames"

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __init__(self, data, x, y, s, c, **kwargs)
    843             # the handling of this argument later
    844             s = 20
--> 845         super(ScatterPlot, self).__init__(data, x, y, s=s, **kwargs)
    846         if is_integer(c) and not self.data.columns.holds_integer():
    847             c = self.data.columns[c]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __init__(self, data, x, y, **kwargs)
    817         if is_integer(y) and not self.data.columns.holds_integer():
    818             y = self.data.columns[y]
--> 819         if len(self.data[x]._get_numeric_data()) == 0:
    820             raise ValueError(self._kind + ' requires x column to be numeric')
    821         if len(self.data[y]._get_numeric_data()) == 0:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2686             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2687         else:
-> 2688             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2689 
   2690     def _getitem_column(self, key):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2693         # get column
   2694         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2695             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2696 
   2697         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   2487         res = cache.get(item)
   2488         if res is None:
-> 2489             values = self._data.get(item)
   2490             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   2491             cache[item] = res

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   4113 
   4114             if not isna(item):
-> 4115                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   4116             else:
   4117                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isna(self.items)]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   3081 
   3082         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Price'
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Check to make sure you have 'Price' column in your dataretry dataframe.

Comment: do `list(dataretry)` and check that `Price` is in there

Comment: Thanks everyone - I learned my "Price" column is actually "Price "